# How to remove empty space below native custom view in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am currently using RN to build a component and use this component in an app.

I have followed RN [guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#integration-with-an-android-fragment-example)  to do so. On my iOs side no issue. But on android i have this big empty space below my component, and I don't know how to get rid of this. Here is the expected result (as it is already the case in iOs) : [view and button below each others with no blank space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNjlz.png)

and here is what I have on android : [view and button below each others with big blank space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96BMC.png)

I have tried to investigate on the android native side of the component, but all i was able to end with was a clue in my manager's manuallyLayoutChildren. Here when I multiply the height and width in view.measure it does change the place filled by my view in my component. But it is not a real solution since it has to be fixed everytime you are changing testing device :

```
 public void manuallyLayoutChildren(View view) {
    // propWidth and propHeight coming from react-native props
    int width = propWidth;
    int height = propHeight;

    view.measure(
      View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
      View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));


    view.layout(0, 0, width, height);

  }
```

my xml is really simple and looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.visioglobe.visiomoveessential.VMEMapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update :

```
view.measure(
      View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
      View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).